# How to check Phone calling service is enable or not in android device?

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager

I want to know that how to check that phone call service is enable or not in different devices, i have Micromax Funbook(p300) Tablet(Android 4.0.3), in which there is no calling service, and i am using below code to check that

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);   
if (tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
    Log.v("TAG", "No calling service");
}else{
    Log.v("TAG", "calling service");
}
```

but this is not working.
it always gives message `calling service` only.

Any help?

Comment: *but this is not working....* what output u are getting when running app?

Comment: it returns 1 (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) from tablet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If calling service is not supported by tablet, google play won't allow the app to be installed on that tablet. Google Play internally checks for permissions which are supported by your device and the permissions the app is asking for, if they do not match, the app is shown as not compatible with your device.
EDIT:
Hence of course, you do not need to check if calling is supported by that device or not...

Comment: Actually if you developer wants to, then the App can be installed on any device. Just have to set the telephony feature as not required and handle it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if device doesn't have facility to make voice call then it must not be a phone.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String ableToMakePhoneCalls = tm.getVoiceMailNumber(); 

//check device for voicemail number (null means no voicemail number).
if(ableToMakePhoneCalls == null)
{ 
     //If the device does not have voicemail, then it must not be a phone. So it can't call. 
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code in tablet and my Micromax A57 cell phone also, return null in all case....